# Passando um array com ajax para o php

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tentando fazer um delete de múltiplos registros, onde tento pegar os `input` com *Ajax* e passar para o *PHP*.

Printando no console consigo ver que estou pegando os valores, mas na hora de passar pro php, não estou conseguindo fazer pegar. Printei no *PHP* e ele não chega nem a entrar no:

```
if (isset($_POST['deleting']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

No *Ajax* o código está assim:

```
$('.delete-form').submit(function(){
    var obj = this;     
    var form = $(obj);
    var submit_btn = $('.delete-form :submit');
    var submit_btn_text = submit_btn.val();
    checkbox = new Array();
        $("input[type=checkbox][name='excluir[]']:checked").each(function(){
            checkbox.push($(this).val());
        });
    console.log(checkbox)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: { excluir : checkbox }
        },
        url: form.attr('action'),
        success: function() {
            alert("Houve algum erro ao excluir!");
        },
        success: function( data ) { 
                    alert(data);
            },
        error: function(){
            alert("Houve algum erro ao tentar excluir!");
        }
    });

return false;})
```

E no *PHP* esta assim:

```
echo 'antes do if';
if (isset($_POST['deleting']) AND $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    echo 'depois do if';
    $data = $_POST['excluir'];
    print_r($data);
    foreach($data as $valor){
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("delete FROM client WHERE id = '$valor'");
        $delete = $sql->execute();
        if($delete){
            echo 'OK';
        }
    }
}
```

Vindo pelo *Ajax*, ele nem entra dentro do `if` do *PHP*. Se eu usar o *PHP* sem o *Ajax*, consigo deletar os registros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota-se no seu script *PHP*, você está verificando se o parâmetro `deleting` existe, mas não encontrei ele em seu *Javascript*.

Adicione ele.

```
data: {
    deleting: true,
    id: { excluir : checkbox }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso e eu quebrando a cabeça sem enxergar.